# Data inserted through PHP does not appear in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a simple PHP page that posts to a DB. I actually only use it for debugging because the real app receives posts from an Arduino:

SamplePost.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="data_post.php" method="post">
  <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name(Temp):</td>
        <td><input name="username" type="text"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      
        <tr>
        <td>Age(co2):</td>
        <td><input name="age" type="text"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>UVIndex:</td>
        <td><input name="uvindex" type="text"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>MQ2:</td>
        <td><input name="mq2" type="text"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I recently used it to debug because I was having issues with the Arduino app not posting since 20 days ago. Oddly enough I discovered the DB username I had in the PHP was incomplete. Odd because it has been posting for years and I honestly don't remember having changed the DB username in the PHP, but whatever. So this is what it posts to:

data_post.php

```
<?php
$user = 'myusr';
$password = 'mypwd';
$server = 'localhost';
$database = 'mydb';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $user, $password);

$username=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$uvindex=$_POST['uvindex'];
$mq2=$_POST['mq2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO example (name,age,uvindex,mq2,beer) VALUES (:username, :age, :uvindex, :mq2, 'NO')";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
$stmt->bindParam(":age", $age);
$stmt->bindParam(":uvindex", $uvindex);
$stmt->bindParam(":mq2", $mq2);

$result = $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':age'=>$age, ':uvindex'=>$uvindex, ':mq2'=>$mq2));

if($result) {
    echo "Your text has been posted";

    }// end if
else {
    echo '0 results';
    }// end else

file_put_contents("arduinopost.txt",$username);
?>
```

So after I corrected the DB username in code, I used the SamplePost.html and it worked because I got my success message from the PHP if-else and I refreshed my DB read file and the post appeared:

query.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusr";
$password = "mypwd";
$dbname = "mydb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM example where id > (SELECT MAX(id) - 20 FROM example)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id=" . $row["id"]. ". Temp=" . $row["name"]. ". CO2PPM=" . $row["age"]. ". UVIndex=" . $row["uvindex"]. ". MQ2R=" . $row["mq2"]. ". Timestamp=" . $row["timestamp"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But the weird thing is that when I look for that entry in the DB via phpMyAdmin, it's simply not there. But I can see the data printed from the query.php on my screen and I've refreshed it multiple times, it's still there...

How can data be in a PHP page that reads from the DB, but not in the DB?

I added the screenshot of phpmyadmin, where are you can see, they records are ordered by descending timestamp, so i should be seeing the latest records, right?

As a side note, the arduino app started posting to the data_post.php page again successfully and I can now see the latest record in my query.php page but I cannot see the records in the phpmyadmin.  Im thinking this is gonna turn up to be something silly but i was worried whatever the cause is, that it might be related to the arduino not being able to post.  But at least now posting is working again.

[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: Mistake in db name, and it's a different db / different server configured on `PHPMyAdmin` / eventually it's about caching configuration .... try `FLUSH TABLES` command.

Comment: ok the db is the same...ive checked in all 3 files, its test.  And Ive logged into my plesk area, the db named test is there, its the only one...

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I think PhpMyAdmin defaults to showing only 25 rows. Are you querying for a specific ID in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: You don't need to use the parameter argument to `$stmt->execute()` if you already used `$stmt->bindParam()`. Just one one or the other.